# Subsetting a CSV by unique column values

Tags: linux, csv, awk, grep

I am fairly new to linux and feel this should be a fairly simple task, but I cannot quite figure it out.  I have a large data file with millions of rows, and I want to break the file into smaller files based on date.  I have a time column that contains YYMMDDHH data, and I want to create sub files based on the DD.  For each new DD, I want a new file created with all entries for that day.  The file is a csv and is already sorted by time.

From what I have read it looks like I should be able to use cat, awk and possibly grep to perform what I want.

To elaborate further,  there are 14 columns per row.  One column has data that contains YYMMDDHH (ie 14071000, 14071000...14071022,14071022....14071100...14071200...)

I can manually subset with

```
cat trial | awk 'NR>=1 && NR<=100 {print}' >output.txt
```

This gives me the rows between 1 and 100.  I was wondering if there is a command that allows me to extract based off the YYMMDDHH column, so that all data points on 140710 could be put in a single file.  Hope that helps explain my problem a little better.

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you more easily, you should add a sample of your input file to the question. Also, it would be good to see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use s.th. like this:

```
awk '{ line_date = $1 / 100; print > "out_" line_date ".txt"; }'
```

BTW you might want to avoid 'useless use of cat' by not piping but using awk directly on your file.

Answer (score 0):

## YYMMDDHH 14071000

imagine YYMMDDHH is at the 1st coloumn.

```
awk '{fn = substr($1, 1, 6) ; print $0 >> fn }' 1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $0 >> "File" substr($1, 0, 6) ".txt"}' file
```

Assuming date is in the first column. Logic is to append each line to corresponding file (name of the file is the date in YYMMDD format). So that all data corresponding to each date will be in corresponding "FileYYMMDD.txt". If date is in some other column, you can just change $1 to the column number.

Sample Output:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ cat file
14071000 asasaa
14071022 iosido
14071000 lsdksld
14071022 sodisdois
14071100 iwiwe
14071022 iosido
14071100 iwiwe
14071200 yqiwyq
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ awk '{print $0 >> "File" substr($1, 0, 6) ".txt"}' file
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ ls
file  File140710.txt  File140711.txt  File140712.txt
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ cat File140710.txt
14071000 asasaa
14071022 iosido
14071000 lsdksld
14071022 sodisdois
14071022 iosido
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ cat File140711.txt
14071100 iwiwe
14071100 iwiwe
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ cat File140712.txt
14071200 yqiwyq
```